# Can't create link when send email using Lotus Notes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, lotus-notes

I'm sorry for bad grammar before, I have case when send message using lotus notes in Python the link I embed in message is not generated as link (not clickable, and generate like plain text) in doc.Body and link not visible using doc.HTMLBody.

```
sess=win32com.client.Dispatch("Notes.NotesSession")
db = sess.getdatabase('','')
db.openmail
agent=db.getAgent("DeleteOldDocs")
doc=db.createdocument
doc.SendTo = recipients
doc.Subject = subject
doc.Body = "Test link http://www.thislink.com"
doc.HTMLBody  = "<a href='http://www.thislink.com'>Link</a>"
doc.send(0)
```

how it possible to send a clickable link in an email message ?

and this is for example:

[This email send by program, and as You can see the link is not clickable and must be copy first then paste to the browser. This is not convenient for the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sEXe.png)

Comment: `http://` is how URLs start. No backslashes.

Comment: @KlausD. I already used double slash too and still not generated as link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NotesMIMEEntity](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESMIMEENTITY_CLASS_OVERVIEW.html) to [create a HTML formatted mail](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21098323).

Your example would look like this then:

```
sess=win32com.client.Dispatch("Notes.NotesSession")
db = sess.getdatabase('','')
stream = sess.CreateStream 
sess.ConvertMIME = False
doc = db.CreateDocument 
doc.Form = "Memo" 
body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity() 
header = body.CreateHeader("Subject") 
header.SetHeaderVal(subject) 
header = body.CreateHeader("To") 
header.SetHeaderVal(recipients) 
stream.writetext("<html><body>") 
stream.writetext("Test link http://www.thislink.com <a href='http://www.thislink.com'>Link</a>") 
stream.writetext("</body></html>") 
body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/HTML;charset=UTF-8", 1728) 
doc.Send(0) 
sess.ConvertMIME = True
```

Comment: thanks before for Your answer sir, I have problem again in this part body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity and I got error like this <COMObject <unknown>>. like I miss something..

Comment: This might be a python specific syntax issue. Does it work with `body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity()` ?

Comment: [Solved] Great ! :) Thank You very much sir, this was issue that I can solve for long time.

Comment: Great it works in python environment too. I added `()` to my answer's code. Did you change something else?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything from Your code, it was work corrrectly. Thank you for your help sir :)